# JavaFX Setting circle fill color from array of Colors

Tags: java, javafx

Searched on google and can only find stuff with awt, but we are using javafx for this class.

As the title states, I need to have a ball change color until a game ends. I have the following code:

```
 Color[] ballColors = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.PURPLE, Color.BLACK};

            for(int i = 0; i <100; i ++){
            myCircle.setFill(ballColors()[i]);
        }
```

the ball is supposed to change color every time the ball is clicked, but it does not. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of for loop try change color of myCircle by:

```
myCircle.setFill(ballColors()[System.currentTimeMillis()%5]);
```

Comment: just had to switch System.currentTimeMillis() to an int and that worked. Thanks